# cordova not loading: object doesn't support property or method addEventListener

Tags: cordova

Am I the only getting the 'object doesn't support property or method addEventListener' error?

here is an image displaying the error with the code:

[image displaying the error](http://is100.imagesocket.com/images/2012/07/06/2496945-9wti.png)

I am using cordova 1.9.0 and developing in Windows Phone, and I am using build.phonegap.com to build the app , and downloading it on an andriod.

In the Windows phone Emulator it runs fine, but when I deploy to phone it does not.

Can this be the reason why it is not running on the actual phone, when I install it ?

**EDIT-SOLVED:**

When using phonegap/cordova build (build.phonegap.com)

Your include script tag src should look like this : 
src="cordova.js", withou any version number in it

And **DO NOT** include the script in your **.zip** file.

Link that helped me :

[cordova not loading after using phonegap build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/getting_started_with_cordova_fails_with_phonegap_build_do_i_need_to_rename_the_cordova_1_9_0_js_file)

Comment: Fantastic, glad you managed to resolve it.